# Vertica : Super projection statement creates two sub projections

Tags: vertica

I created a table Employee and super projection with KSAFE 1.

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(ssid varchar(255)..);

CREATE PROJECTION Employee_SUPER(ssid..)
AS
 SELECT Employee.ssid,
 FROM Employee
 ORDER BY Employee.location_id
SEGMENTED BY hash(Employee.location_id) ALL NODES KSAFE 1;
```

But I wanted to know why would it create two projections under the same? 
Both of these projections are named as Employee_SUPER_b0 and Employee_SUPER_b1.

Attached is the image of Squirrel.

[Vertica projection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSCjZ.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read about `Buddy Projections` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vertica creates copies (buddy projections) of the segmented projections in order to reach the wanted k-safety. In your case (k-safety=1) you will have one copy of your segmented projections across nodes. The distribution of the "buddy projections" is controlled by the OFFSET parameter (default 1).

You might want to have a look to the [fine manual](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ConceptsGuide/Components/K-Safety.htm%3FTocPath%3DVertica%2520Concepts%7CVertica%2520Platform%7CHigh%2520Availability%7C_____1)